# How many elements does $\mathcal{P}(A)$ have?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> Let $A$ be a set of size fifteen. Let $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denote the power set of $A$, that is the set of all the subsets of $A$. How many elements does $\mathcal{P}(A)$ contain?

This is the same as being $0$ or $1$, binary sets of size $1\to 14$?

Does this mean the answer is

${15\choose 0} + {15\choose 1} + {15\choose 2} +\dots +{15\choose 13}+{15\choose 14}+{15\choose 15}$?

Or is there something I am not considering?

Comment: Of size $0$ to $15$. Your expression is right. It is not really needed, the number is $2^{15}$.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but note that it can be expressed in a much simpler form, namely $(1+1)^{15} = 2^{15}$. This is a result of the binomial theorem: $(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k y^{n-k}$ with $x=y=1$. Another way to think about it is that each of the $15$ elements can be included or excluded, so there are $2^{15}$ possibilities.

Comment: @Bungo Ahhh, that was the direction my logic was going with the binary comparison, but I guess it didn't fully click!

Comment: Or you even can show using induction for example that any power set of  a finite set has cardinality $2^{\#\text{ set}}$

Comment: @JoseAntonio That was $2^{\text{ size of set }}$?

Comment: Yes, or you can show a bijective map from $\{0,1\}^n\to \mathcal{P}(n)$ and the result is almost trivial, hint: use the indicator function.  $n$ is the set with $n$ elements sorry for the notation is late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sum is correct, and moreover in general:

$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}=2^n.$$

So another way of realising your sum is $2^{15}$.

A combintorical proof that the size of the power set of an $n$ element set $A$ is $2^n$ (which can also be used to prove the above identity) is as follows.

There is a bijection between subsets $X\subset A$ and $n$-bit binary sequences, where there is a 1 in the $i$th position of the sequence iff the $i$th element of $A$ is in the corresponding subset. It is easy to show that this is a bijection. Moreover, the number of $n$-bit binary sequences is clearly $2^n$ (you have two choices for each of the $n$ bits). This proves the claim.

Comment: Thank you, that does make sense! One further question: How many bits strings are there containing exactly nine $0$’s and six $1$’s, if every 1 must be
followed immediately by a $0$?

Would I pair the $10$'s up getting me $3 \;\;0$'s and $6$ pairs, meaning I just have to look at number of combinations of this? $\frac{9!}{6!3!}$

Comment: Yes that's right, if you rewrote it so that each of the "10" pairs were a 2, then you are counting the number of ways to arrange three 0's and six 2's, which gives $\frac{9!}{3!6!}$.

Comment: It turns out that for this reason, the power set of $A$ is sometimes written $2^A$.