# How many subsets does a set $S$ with $n$ elements have?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many subsets does a set $S$ with $n$ elements have?

I think the product principle can be used to answer this question. But I am not sure how it applies. I tried to do this by finding all of the subsets for $n=1, 2, 3$ but I couldn't find a pattern because I was probably doing it wrong. For example when $n=2$ we could have a subset with just the first element, just the second element, both elements, or the empty set, this gives us $4$ subsets when $n=2$, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Now try $3$. Be _very_ methodical about how you do it. You will see an immediate pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.

You can use the bijection

$$\varphi: \mathcal P(S)\to\{0,1\}^n.$$

Basically, if an element is in the subset you consider, you give the value $1$, and if not $0$.

So $\vert \mathcal P(S)\vert =\vert \{0,1\}^n\vert =2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a duplicate of the question [How many elements does $\mathcal{P}(A)$ have?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936036/how-many-elements-does-mathcalpa-have).

The collection of subsets of a set $A$ is called the *powerset* of $A$ and is denoted $\mathcal{P}(A)$. If $A$ has $n$ elements, there are $2^n$ sets in the powerset.

To see this, think of any subset of a set $A = \{ a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ as a sequence of $n$ choices. At step no. $i$ you choose whether or not the element $a_i$ should be in the subset or not. There are $\underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdots 2}_{n \mbox{ times}} = 2^n$ such sequences, since at every step you have $2$ possible choices.